# HDMI Output for App On IPad 2

Tags: iphone, ipad, ipad-2

Im just wondering if there is any code needed in application to utilize the new HDMI output ability with the iPad 2? Or is it the fact that you just plug it in and it will just replicate what is on the iPad screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this game: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blaster-through-asteroid-field/id414827482?mt=8 before the iPad2 came out, without any specific code to output the display. When my iPad2 came in I was able to plug it into a projector as-is and display it live on both the iPad and the projector simultaneously (no noticeable latency either.. pretty impressive I think). So no, you probably don't need any special code. I would still test if you're doing any non-standard rendering.